# Texmaker bibliography issues (no article helped so far...)

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, texmaker, jabref

I am currently preparing my research proposals. I have three general topics left. Before focusing on only one, I would like to hand in a single document with all three research proposals on (and three bibliographies) with the following structure:

**Topic 1**

1. Idea and hypothesis -> text
2. Literature -> bibliography (using \nocite(*))
3. Methodology -> text

**Topic 2**

1. Idea and hypothesis -> text (some \cite(...))
2. Literature -> bibliography (using \nocite(*))
3. Methodology -> text

**Topic 3**

1. Idea and hypothesis -> text (some \cite(...))
2. Literature -> bibliography (using \nocite(*))
3. Methodology -> text

I am using TexMaker and JabRef. I also tried all given possibilities of using either, some or all used packages under %Bibliography. Below my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%Layout
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

%Bibliography
%\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%Other packages
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

%====================================================================
%   RESEARCH PROPOSALS
%====================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
Research Proposals
\end{LARGE}

\begin{enumerate}
%====================================================================
%   1 - DIVESTITURE STRATEGIES
%====================================================================
\item \textsc{Divestiture strategies}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
text
%================================

\medskip 
\begin{large}
\textit{Literature}
\end{large}\\
%================================
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % others are: unsrt / plain / alpha
\bibliography{literature_divestitures}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
%   2 - DEBT RENEGOTIATION
%====================================================================
\bigskip 
\item \textsc{Debt renegotiation}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
Text cite{asonuma2012serial,bai2012duration,bester1994role,favara2014debt,favara2015debt,moraux2014inside,saleh2005earnings,yue2010sovereign}) text
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Literature}
\end{large}\\
%================================
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % others are: unsrt / plain / alpha
\bibliography{literature_debtrenegotiation}
%================================
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
%   3 - HEDGE FUND ACTIVISM
%====================================================================
\bigskip 
\item \textsc{Hedge funds activism}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
text
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Literature}
\end{large}\\

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % others are: unsrt / plain / alpha
\bibliography{literature_hedgefunds}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The issue is, even though the bib files are in the same folder and I ran the usual quick build (1x pdflatex, 1x bibtex, 2x pdflatex) the bibliography doesn't show up and the citations made in the text are shown as **[?]**.

Where is the mistake in the code? In my TexMaker code \bibliography{...} stays blue and doesn't turn to the usual code colors of grey/red. I am eternally grateful for you help.

Best
Kim

Below my bib files (bibtex):

*literature_debtrenegotiation.bib*

```
@Article{favara2014debt,
  author  = {Favara, Giovanni and Morellec, Erwan and Schroth, Enrique and Valta, Philip},
  title   = {Debt renegotiation and investment decisions across countries},
  journal = {Unpublished Working Paper},
  year    = {2014},
}

@Article{favara2015debt,
  author = {Favara, Giovanni and Morellec, Erwan and Schroth, Enrique and Valta, Philip},
  title  = {Debt Renegotiation, Investment, and Risk Taking Across Countries},
  year   = {2015},
}

@Article{bai2012duration,
  author    = {Bai, Yan and Zhang, Jing},
  title     = {Duration of sovereign debt renegotiation},
  journal   = {Journal of international Economics},
  year      = {2012},
  volume    = {86},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {252--268},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}

@Article{saleh2005earnings,
  author    = {Saleh, Norman Mohd and Ahmed, Kamran},
  title     = {Earnings management of distressed firms during debt renegotiation},
  journal   = {Accounting and Business Research},
  year      = {2005},
  volume    = {35},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {69--86},
  publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
}

@Article{moraux2014inside,
  author    = {Moraux, Franck and Silaghi, Florina},
  title     = {Inside debt renegotiation: Optimal debt reduction, timing, and the number of rounds},
  journal   = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
  year      = {2014},
  volume    = {27},
  pages     = {269--295},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}

@Article{asonuma2012serial,
  author  = {Asonuma, Tamon},
  title   = {Serial default and debt renegotiation},
  journal = {Browser Download This Paper},
  year    = {2012},
}

@Article{yue2010sovereign,
  author    = {Yue, Vivian Z},
  title     = {Sovereign default and debt renegotiation},
  journal   = {Journal of international Economics},
  year      = {2010},
  volume    = {80},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {176--187},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}

@Article{bester1994role,
  author    = {Bester, Helmut},
  title     = {The role of collateral in a model of debt renegotiation},
  journal   = {Journal of money, credit and banking},
  year      = {1994},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {72--86},
  publisher = {JSTOR},
}
```

*literature_divestitures.bib*

```
@Article{hoskisson1994,
  author    = {Hoskisson, Robert E and Johnson, Richard A and Moesel, Douglas D},
  title     = {Corporate divestiture intensity in restructuring firms: Effects of governance, strategy, and performance},
  journal   = {Academy of Management journal},
  year      = {1994},
  volume    = {37},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {1207--1251},
  publisher = {Academy of Management},
}

@Article{woo1992spin,
  author    = {Woo, Carolyn Y and Willard, Gary E and Daellenbach, Urs and others},
  title     = {Spin-off performance: A case of overstated expectations?},
  journal   = {Strategic Management Journal},
  year      = {1992},
  volume    = {13},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {433--447},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}

@Article{jain1994post,
  author    = {Jain, Bharat A and Kini, Omesh},
  title     = {The post-issue operating performance of IPO firms},
  journal   = {The journal of finance},
  year      = {1994},
  volume    = {49},
  number    = {5},
  pages     = {1699--1726},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}

@Article{krishnan2011venture,
  author    = {Krishnan, CNV and Ivanov, Vladimir I and Masulis, Ronald W and Singh, Ajai K},
  title     = {Venture capital reputation, post-IPO performance, and corporate governance},
  journal   = {Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {46},
  number    = {05},
  pages     = {1295--1333},
  publisher = {Cambridge Univ Press},
}
```

*literature_hedgefunds.bib*

```
@Article{krishnan2016second,
  author    = {Krishnan, CNV and Partnoy, Frank and Thomas, Randall S},
  title     = {The second wave of hedge fund activism: The importance of reputation, clout, and expertise},
  journal   = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
  year      = {2016},
  volume    = {40},
  pages     = {296--314},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
}

@Article{coffee2016wolf,
  author    = {Coffee Jr, John C and Palia, Darius and others},
  title     = {The Wolf at the Door: The Impact of Hedge Fund Activism on Corporate Governance},
  journal   = {Ann§als of Corporate Governance},
  year      = {2016},
  volume    = {1},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1--94},
  publisher = {Now Publishers, Inc.},
}
```

Comment: This isn't a TeXMaker issue, the trouble is you're using multiple `.bib` files, and you'll need a package to help. Maybe take a look at this page for ideas: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-multbib.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `biblatex`, which is easier to customise, has  an `apa` style. Preferably compile with `biber`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Layout
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

%Bibliography
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\addbibresource{literature_divestitures.bib}
\addbibresource{literature_debtrenegotiation.bib}%
\addbibresource{literature_hedgefunds.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
 \map{
 \perdatasource{literature_divestitures.bib}
 \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=DS, append]
 }
 \map{
 \perdatasource{literature_debtrenegotiation.bib}
 \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=DR, append]
 }
 \map{
 \perdatasource{literature_hedgefunds.bib}
 \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=HF, append]
 }
 }
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literature}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\itshape}
%Other packages
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

%====================================================================
% RESEARCH PROPOSALS
%====================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
Research Proposals
\end{LARGE}

\begin{enumerate}
%====================================================================
% 1 - DIVESTITURE STRATEGIES
%====================================================================
\item \textsc{Divestiture strategies}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}
%================================
text
%%================================
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Literature, keyword=DS]
%%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}
%
%====================================================================
% 2 - DEBT RENEGOTIATION
%====================================================================
\bigskip
\item \textsc{Debt renegotiation}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
Text \cite{asonuma2012serial,bai2012duration,favara2014debt,favara2015debt,moraux2014inside,saleh2005earnings,yue2010sovereign}) text
%================================
\printbibliography[title=Literature, keyword=DR]
%================================
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
% 3 - HEDGE FUND ACTIVISM
%====================================================================
\bigskip
\item \textsc{Hedge funds activism}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
text
%================================
\printbibliography[title=Literature, keyword=HF]
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}
%
%====================================================================
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my earlier comment, you can use the `multibbl` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%Layout
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

%Bibliography
%\usepackage[]{natbib}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{divestitures}
\newbibliography{debtrenegotiation}
\newbibliography{hedgefunds}

%====================================================================
%   RESEARCH PROPOSALS
%====================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
Research Proposalssd
\end{LARGE}

\begin{enumerate}
%====================================================================
%   1 - DIVESTITURE STRATEGIES
%====================================================================
\item \textsc{Divestiture strategies}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
text
%================================
\nocite{divestitures}{*}
\bibliographystyle{divestitures}{apalike}
\bibliography{divestitures}{literature-divestitures}{\large\it Literature}

%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
%   2 - DEBT RENEGOTIATION
%====================================================================
\bigskip 
\item \textsc{Debt renegotiation}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
Text \cite{hedgefunds}{asonuma2012serial,bai2012duration,bester1994role,favara2014debt,favara2015debt,moraux2014inside,saleh2005earnings,yue2010sovereign}) text

%================================
\nocite{debtrenegotiation}{*}
\bibliographystyle{debtrenegotiation}{apalike} 
\bibliography{debtrenegotiation}{literature-debtrenegotiation}{\large\it Literature}
%================================
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
%   3 - HEDGE FUND ACTIVISM
%====================================================================
\bigskip 
\item \textsc{Hedge funds activism}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Idea and hypothesis}
\end{large}\\
%================================
text
%================================
\nocite{hedgefunds}{*}
\bibliographystyle{hedgefunds}{apalike} 
\bibliography{hedgefunds}{literature-hedgefunds}{\large\it Literature}
%================================

\medskip
\begin{large}
\textit{Methodology}
\end{large}\\
%
%====================================================================
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, for this to work I had to remove the `cite` and `cleveref` packages, because `multibbl` redefines commands like `\cite` to take two arguments: the first of these is the bibliography you want to cite from.

To compile the above, after running `latex` (or `pdflatex`) as usual, you need to do `bibtex divestitures`, `bibtex debtrenegotiation` and `bibtex hedgefunds` to run `bibtex` on all three bibliographies. You then need to run `latex` (or `pdflatex`) twice more. Some TeX editors will have build sequences that know to run `bibtex` on these different aux files, while for others you may just have to do it from a command prompt.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer. Were you able to generate a pdf with concerning bibliographies? I implemented your code but still "no show" in case of the bibliographies.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have a PDF showing the three bibliographies correctly. You need to run bibtex on all three bibliographies separately, i.e. issue the commands `bibtex divestitures`, `bibtex debtrenegotiation` and `bibtex hedgefunds`. Some TeX Editors know to do this automatically, but maybe TeXMaker doesn't.